# With scala.meta replacing scala.reflect, what will happen to ClassTags and TypeTags?

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, introspection, scalameta

Or is this even relevant?

What I have in mind is using the `ClassTag` or `TypeTag` annotations, like so:

```
scala>
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

def f[T : TypeTag](ls : List[T]) : String = {
  ???
}
```

results in :

```
f: [T](ls: List[T])(implicit evidence$1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T])String
```

As you can see, the `TypeTag` is seen by the compiler which adds an implicit argument. Is there an equivalent in `scala.meta`? How will this work, and will there be any changes in the way erasure is handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment `scala.meta` does not provide runtime introspection, however, that's planned for future releases. APIs would be similar to `scala.reflect` (but in terms of `scala.meta`, e.g. different `Abstract Syntax Trees`, no exposed compiler internals, etc), and I really hope that end user wont see much difference.

So, functionality of `ClassTag/TypeTag` is not likely to disappear. Most probably, `scala.meta` will use a bridge (`paradise`) to get access to `scalac` internals (and that involves `scala.reflect`).

Also note that `scala.reflect` will be supported in `scala 2.x` branch, but not in `dotty`.